# Is live.de allowed to block mails from my clean mailserver?

Tags: linux, email-server

I have a very small mailserver running.

Everyone is accepting my mails - even google does - except live.de. I once had to fill in a form to identify myself as a legit mail sender, but after I moved to another IP, my mails get rejected again.

To me, forcing me to identify myself as a "legit" mailsender beyond configuring my server properly, seems an offense. 
Since I cannot contact any customer using live.de, I also have a business-issue with these circumstances.

My MX is clean. It **never** was on any blacklist and never spammed around.
Yes, of course it's legal for them to do pretty much whatever they want with their email service. Unfortunately you have little to no recourse. That's life on the internet, though.
So my question is simply: Is this legal / What's the legal ground for this extra check ?

**Update**

@EEAA

> Yes, of course it's legal for them to do pretty much whatever they want with their email service.

Right, they are free to do whatever they want with their services. But in practice this means a use of market force to obtain (and export) data from competitors and private persons for no reason. So there are several legal aspects involved. This could easily explain, why no one else is practicing  this kind of spam management.

Comment: Oh com on, please. Be civilised,

Comment: What is wrong with you guys? Why all the downvotes?

Comment: Legal questions are better suited for [law.se], though I don't expect the answer to be something you'll be happy with. You can always tell those customers to switch to a provider which does not block legitimate emails.

Comment: "It never was on any blacklist"  <--- that's a pretty bold statement. How can you be sure of this?

Comment: @EEAA No, it never was. I never had issues with any other mail provider.

Comment: Even a year later the response seems to be a proof of kindergarden. And theese checks miraculously seem to have stopped. Thank you MS!

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is simply: Is this legal / What's the legal ground for
>   this extra check ?

Yes, of course it's legal for them to do pretty much whatever they want with their email service. Unfortunately you have little to no recourse. That's life on the internet, though.

Comment: Dunno. I think mail was meant to be a one-class-system. So, if you provide "mail", you must comply with the "mail" standard (RFC) or call it ... eg. iMail,

Comment: There's a big difference between adhering to standards and legality.

Comment: Maybe you could  clarify.

Comment: RFCs specify the "standard" way one should operate systems, to maximize interoperability with other systems. RFCs are in no way legally binding.

Comment: @ansi_lumen: The mail related RFCs are technical standards to help systems interoperate and there is no law that would require anyone to follow them,  they are not DIN or ANSI standards that you need to follow to do business. Also, these standards allow you to reject mail for whatever reason anyway.

Comment: I know the difference between RFCs and DIN norms. My point is, that they use their market force to make me do stuff, I don't have to do, which results in obtained data about me and my mailserver. Which may leave my country illegally.

Comment: Right - you don't have to do it. And they don't have to accept mail from you nor any other mail system.

Comment: But can call themselves a "mail provider". I will have that checked.