# Trouble setting up mail server(postfix, dovecot) on centos

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, centos7

I'm having trouble setting up my mail server, i have followed this tutorial: http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-centos-7/. Now i'm trying to send mails to my outlook adress, but i can't because it says **connection timed out**, when it tries to connect to the outlook servers.

Log:

```
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost postfix/cleanup[17615]: 1ABC5100053E7: message-id=<>
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost postfix/qmgr[17027]: 1ABC5100053E7: from=<joonas@dynavio.com>, size=3067, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost postfix/smtpd[17607]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.1.103]
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.168.1.103, lip=192.168.1.100, TLS, session=<KNiSR2wvSQDAqAFn>
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.168.1.103, lip=192.168.1.100, TLS, session=<SzKTR2wvSwDAqAFn>
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.168.1.103, lip=192.168.1.100, session=<lFaTR2wvTQDAqAFn>
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.168.1.103, lip=192.168.1.100, session=<xHuTR2wvTwDAqAFn>
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.168.1.103, lip=192.168.1.100, TLS, session=<pAuUR2wvUQDAqAFn>
Apr  1 16:23:07 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.168.1.103, lip=192.168.1.100, TLS, session=<w3CUR2wvUwDAqAFn>
Apr  1 16:23:37 localhost postfix/smtp[17616]: connect to mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25: Connection timed out
Apr  1 16:24:07 localhost postfix/smtp[17616]: connect to mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.33.119]:25: Connection timed out
Apr  1 16:24:37 localhost postfix/smtp[17616]: connect to mx2.hotmail.com[65.54.188.72]:25: Connection timed out
```

Comment: `connect to mx2.hotmail.com[65.54.188.72]:25: Connection timed out` - Many (residential) ISP's and organisations block outgoing SMTP traffic (TCP/IP port 25) and to send email they require you to configure their SMTP server as a relay.

Comment: Yeah i have opened port 568 as well, but it seems to use 25 still

Comment: It would be nice if i could be answered more.

Comment: i have opened port 587*

Comment: 1) Confirm that port 25 is actually blocked because that is what your server needs to directly deliver email to the world 2) Find out where it is blocked (check your own firewalls first, before blaming your ISP) and see if you can open it 3) If port 25 is indeed blocked, there may be a relay server/smarthost that you can configure in postfix. Alternatively operate your own relay server outside your restricted network where you can configure an alternative port that isn't blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a serious email server on a dynamic IP - you need to have a static IP and if its in a residential block you have to check the various blackhole lists and make sure your IP is delisted. Most email systems check that people trying to send them emails are genuine properly configured email servers and not someone's home computer that has been taken over by a spambot. Once you have a static IP you need to set up a SPF record on the DNS that manages the domain its on.

Answer (score 0):

1. You send from a dynamic IP. I would not take any mail from you without a login (smtp/imap)
2. Microsoft runs a so-called "Service Police Framework" (SPF) which may block you from sending to live.*/hotmail.com in the beginning. (see: [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/766592/is-live-de-allowed-to-block-mails-from-my-clean-mailserver)) You'll have to fill in a form, if so, to get permission to send emails to them.

Comment: Ok, but it's still possible to receivice mails? What do you recommend to do to solve this problem?